# Cannot load image from my computer in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load image from my computer on my jupyter notebook.I have searched in the net and stackoverflow and got some codes mentioned below

```
##method1(in code cell)
from IPython.display import Image
Image('imagepath.jpg')               

##method2(in code cell)
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename=('imagepath.jpg'))               

method3(in markdown cell)
![title]('imagepath.png')
```

It seams  that it worked for some users as i was seeing answer in other posts.
But none of these methods work for me..Can anyone shed some light in this matter?.
P.S-I am able to load image through url of image from internet.

Answer (score 0):

The same code you showed is working for me.

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image("C:\\Users\\Bhuvanesh\\Pictures\\b2.jpg")
```

Add your error message here. That will be helpful for others to guide you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help it seems there was some problem with my system

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too. Just change the cell setting from "Code" to "Markdown" before running this code:

```
![](image_filename.png)
```